# Can not use JNA: com.sun.jna.Library is not accessible

Tags: java, jna, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I am trying to use JNA, because I want to work with a .dll that was written in c++ and the rest of my code is in Java. However, if I try to import the JNA classes Eclipse claims "The type com.sun.jna.Library is not accessible".

My IDE seems to see that JNA is somehow in my libraries because when I type "import com.sun.j" it proposes .jna and the other packages in the .jar files to me.

I have created a seperate Project to see if it works there, but it just doesnt work.

I have downloaded the latest .jar (jna-5.8.0.jar and jna-platform-5.8.0.jar) files from the jna Github (https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/README.md ) and I have added them to the class path via project-> configure Buildpath -> add External JARs

I am using Eclipse with javaSE-13.

```java
package Testtest;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Package strcuture:

```
Test
 |-- src
 |   |-- TestTest
 |   |   |-- Main.java
 |   |-- module-info.java
 |-- JRE System Library [JavaSE-13]
 |-- Referenced Libraries
     |-- jna-5.8.0.jar
     |-- jna-platform-5.8.0.jar
```

Comment: You have a 'module-info.java' so your project is using the module system introduced in Java 9 which makes setting up the classpath more complex. Just delete the module-info.java file to revert to the simpler way of doing things.

Answer (score 5):

As [@greg-449](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449) mentioned in the comments, you have a modular project, indicated by the presence of the `module-info.java` file in your `src` directory (package root).

You have three options here:

- run on (or change your project compatibility level to) JRE 8 or earlier which ignores `module-info.java`
- delete the `module-info.java` module descriptor in order to run your program without modules
- edit your module descriptor (`module-info.java`) to add the directive `requires com.sun.jna`.  If you're using `jna-platform` then also add `requires com.sun.jna.platform`.

  - In addition, if you extend any JNA classes like `Structure` or `PointerType` you will need to `open` any packages in your project containing those subclasses to `com.sun.jna` because they use reflection to access your subclasses.  (There are multiple options here, but `open TestTest to com.sun.jna` is the closest to JDK8 behavior.). I am aware this is just a test setup, but consider a reverse-DNS-style package name and module descriptor.
  - If you are using JNA on the module path you may prefer to use the `jna-jpms-5.8.0` and `jna-platform-jpms-5.8.0` JARs as your dependencies, as they have their own module descriptors.